# Update inner array's element in array of arrays in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following mongodb document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : "c6b8S5Rx8xZiL42WS",
    "rows" : [
                [
                        {
                                "row" : 1,
                                "col" : 1,
                                "reserved" : false
                        },
                        {
                                "row" : 1,
                                "col" : 2,
                                "reserved" : false
                        },
                ],
                [
                        {
                                "row" : 2,
                                "col" : 1,
                                "reserved" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "row" : 2,
                                "col" : 2,
                                "reserved" : false
                        },
                ],
            ]
}
```

- Is it possible to somehow update for example the inner object where
  *row=1* and *col=1* in this document?
- Or should I just change the whole document's structure/maybe create a
  new collection?

Comment: What is your mongo version ?

Comment: It's Mongo 3.4.5 which I unfortunately can't update because I'm using a framework called Meteor.js that uses it's own supported version of mongo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below update.

Note the use of double `$elemMatch` to reach the nested array and use positional operator with `$set` and index variable to update the inner array element.

Positional operator returns the index of outer array.

```
db.col.update(
  {
    "_id": "c6b8S5Rx8xZiL42WS",
    "rows": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "row": 1,
          "col": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
 { "$set": { ['rows.$.' + index + '.reserved']: true } } 
)
```

Comment: For some reason it matches the document but it doesn't update it for me, it says:  { "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 }

Comment: Which query did you use ? Use first one

Comment: I used the first one but I think I did something wrong. Here's what I'd like to achieve: I want to update the inner object's reserved field to true where row=1, col=1 without modifying the structure of the document. How should I modify your query?

Comment: Sorry I mixed up your question with some other question. Deep level updates is not possible in 3.4 but you can try something like `db.col.update(
  {
    "_id": "c6b8S5Rx8xZiL42WS",
    "rows": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "row": 1,
          "col": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "rows.$.0.reserved": true
    }
  }
)`. Note I'm using 0 index to refer to first element inside inner array. So if you have that kind of flexibility it may work for your use case or else you have model the collection in a more update friendly way.

Comment: This would work for me but I would have to make the "0" in the "rows.$.0.reserved" to be dynamic based on a parameter because I'm making this update from a function. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes try `{ "$set": { ['rows.$.' + index + '.reserved']: true } }` and pass the index value.

Comment: Thank you, it's working! If you could update your answer then I'll accept it.

Comment: @s7vr how can we know index value..?